# Software requires a graphics driver with at least OpenGL 3.3 support

Tags: intel-graphics, blender

my laptop is a Samsung P530 with Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 330 2.13GHz and Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller inside. I’m a Fedora Linux user and I’m using version 29, it’s excellent Linux Distro, however, I have problems starting the Blender 3D 2.8 and in the terminal prompt I read this message: “Blender requires a graphics driver with at least OpenGL 3.3 support.The program will now close.”.
So I investigated a bit:

```
my graphical drivers in use - driver=i915 latency=0
direct rendering - Yes
the version of OpenGL present in the system - OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 18.2.8
```

I saw the Intel web site but I noticed that the graphic drivers for Linux aren’t more supported.

Could any of you help me to resolve this problem ?

Thanks for reading me and you have a great time, Rino.

Comment: What exactly is the question?  You need to install the Intel display drivers in order for your system to support OpenGL 3.3 (provided the hardware actually supports).  If you cannot install the Intel Linux drivers then your system is incompatible with OpenGL 3.3

Answer (score 0):

This is not a driver problem, it is hardware. Your system is too old and the built-in graphics do not support what you require.

You can either use older versions of Blender or you can buy newer hardware.

From [what I can find](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/hd_graphics_(ironlake)) your [CPU/GPU](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i3/i3-330m) is limited to OpenGL 2.1.

There are no other solutions.